# iPad connects to Wifi but not to Internet

Tags: ios, ipad, network, wifi, internet

I am trying to connect my iPad to the Internet without success.I am able to connect to the Wifi network but not to the Internet from there. This router (let's call it WIFI A) I am connecting to is connected via cable to the LAN main access point, which also works as a Wifi access point (let's call it WIFI B). Now I am able to connect to the Internet using WIFI B, but can't connect to the Internet using WIFI A.

I can normally connect to WIFI A, but no Internet from there. I can also connect to the Internet when using WIFI A with other devices and computers, but can't connect with any Apple device.

There are some options regarding the Wifi connections that I can change, but I don't know what to change.

Does anyone have any ideas?