# iPad can't connect to internet

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

[iPad connects to Wifi but not to Internet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143425/ipad-connects-to-wifi-but-not-to-internet) is similar, but has no answer, and is **incorrectly** tagged a duplicate of one that refers to a **laptop**.

Our iPad with up-to-date O.S. can connect to either of our two WiFi SSIDs or to an iPhone hotspot.  Settings shows the connection, but the WiFi/hotspot icons do not appear in the status bar, and internet access stalls.

Router is a Airport.  DNS was an IPv6 address first and 1.1.1.1 second.  I changed it to 1.1.1.1 first and 8.8.8.8 second.  Didn't help.  Then changed IP address from auto (DHCP) to an arbitrary high number in our netmask range (in case a static IP device was on the same address).  Still nothing.

MacBook Pro and iPhone are exchanging data via iCloud and Dropbox with no problem.

UPDATE: Two-button reboot had no effect, but one-button reboot fixed it.  Oddly, however, about an hour later, the iPhone had the same symptoms.  And a reboot did not fix this one.

UPDATE 2: Eventually, the iPhone started working.  But then the iPad started doing it again.  Every time it happened was immediately after establishing a link between Account Tracker Pro and Dropbox on that particular device.  BUT, this problem has happened three times, and the Dropbox connection was done six times.

Comment: Can the iPad browse and connect to devices on the same subnet as itself?

Comment: It has long been a peeve of mine that most if not all apps that do that sort of thing insist on going through iCloud or some other server.  The only exception I am aware of is AirPrint, and indeed, the iPhone (which now has the problem) cannot find the printer, but the iPad can now find it.  oops: it found the printer, but it took ages.  It's still failing to do anything outside, and still not showing the WiFi icon.

Comment: I have Hurricane Electric app and Prompt app and they can probe for open ports - ssh and more to Macs and other servers. Files can connect to any SMB share - there are tons of things that work exclusively local so my point was is the problem routing out of your local network or the problem with the iPad. It wasn't clear from the version of the post when I commented. It's still not clear after the reboots if you have a local issue or routing one.

Comment: Really seems like a router issue: reboot fixed the iPad but then the iPhone developed the same problem, and neither reboot of the iPhone nor of the router can fix it.  And of course, without internet access, I cannot add any kind of diagnostic app to the iPhone.  But the MBP can ping the iPhone.

Comment: Rebooted router with everything else off.  Then turned them all on: iPhone automatically "connected" to an old SSID that no longer exists and was not detected yesterday!  No IP address, because that router isn't around to serve DHCP.  Switched to the SSID that is working for the others, but iPhone still no access.  Then connected to the router with Airport Utility.  Opened the edit screen but did not change anything.  Clicked update, and when it came back, the iPhone can get App Store but cannot connect to dropbox.

Comment: Have you reset the Network Settings of the devices experiencing issues? This can be found in Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.

Comment: Nope.  Having to rebuild stuff like that is the LAST resort.